# How to terminate gurobi callback using pyomo?

Tags: callback, pyomo, gurobi

I am using pyomo and its 'gurobi_persistent'-interface to solve a MIP. I was trying to implement a callback, that checks for a sufficiently small optimality-gap and will terminate, if it is reached. Of course, this must happen in a way, where the current solution will be read back to the pyomo model. I am not sure how to do that. When the stop condition is fulfilled, I get

> AttributeError: 'GurobiPersistent' object has no attribute 'terminate'

Typically, in gurobipy, the statement model.terminate() should work.
Also see my callback definition below.

```
solver = pe.SolverFactory('gurobi_persistent')
solver.set_instance(m)

def my_callback(cb_m, cb_opt, cb_where):
    if cb_where == GRB.Callback.MIP:
        # General MIP callback
        objbst = cb_opt.cbGet(GRB.Callback.MIP_OBJBST)
        objbnd = cb_opt.cbGet(GRB.Callback.MIP_OBJBND)
        if abs(objbst - objbnd) < percentGap * (1.0 + abs(objbst)):
            print('Stop early - {} % gap achieved'.format(percentGap*100))
            # statement that does not exist
            cb_opt.terminate()
solver.set_callback(my_callback)
solver.solve(tee=True)
```

I would be grateful for some hints on how to achieve the desired behavior.
Have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From checking the Pyomo docs on [gurobi_direct](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/pyomo/solvers/plugins/solvers/gurobi_direct.html) and [gurobi_persistent](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/pyomo/solvers/plugins/solvers/gurobi_persistent.html) it seems like this is simply not possible. You would need to implement your callback using the Gurobi Python API.

Another way of implementing a certain MIPGap is to simply set this gap as a [termination value](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/mipgap2.html).

Comment: Hey Matt, thank you for your answer. Sometimes Pyomo can be cumbersome. Originally, I did only plan to solve MIP models (for gas networks based on works done at ZIB, actually =)). After encountering some problems with the callbacks a year ago or so, I went straight to gurobipy. Now, however, I might implement some nonlinear models as well, and went back to Pyomo to be able to use other solvers, such as SCIP. The MIPGap parameter suggestion is a good hint and should do the trick. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to use SCIP anyway, you should try [PySCIPOpt](https://github.com/scipopt/PySCIPOpt) to avoid the Pyomo layer.